# Assign a Get-WebAppPoolState returned value to a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell

This code:

> import-module WebAdministration
>
> Get-WebAppPoolState AppPoolName

Produces the following output:

> Value 
>   - -
>   Stopped

But this code:

> import-module WebAdministration
>
> $state = Get-WebAppPoolState AppPoolName
>
> WRITE-HOST $state

Produces this output:

> Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.CodeProperty

When I get the state of the App Pool using Get-WebAppPoolState, I need a boolean value of some sort to assign to the variable so I can use it in a conditional statement.

I cant use the Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.CodeProperty line.

How do I correct this?

Comment: Any final solution? Mark the answer then.

Answer (score 19):

Get-WebAppPoolState is not returning a string but an object of type CodeProperty. You'll want the Value property from that object, i.e.:

```
$state = (Get-WebAppPoolState AppPoolName).Value;
```

I presume some display converter is kicking in the first case when it gets written to output which is why Stopped is displayed but not for writing to host so you get the default object representation (which is the type name) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That makes perfect sense.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but does this work better?

```
$state = $(Get-WebAppPoolState AppPoolName)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately no, it gives the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet with `ExpandProperty` to get the value of 1 or more properties from an object.

```
$pool = "app-pool-name"
$state = Get-WebAppPoolState $pool | Select -ExpandProperty Value
Write-Host $state
```